# what is OpenNLP's model file path?

Tags: android, eclipse, opennlp

I try to use OpenNLP in an Android application with eclipse, and I imported the 4 JARs into the libs folder.

It's probably a stupid question.. but where should I put the model files "en-pos-maxent.bin"? I can't find anything regarding the path anywhere

I try to run the code contains this line:

```
POSModel model = new POSModelLoader()   
            .load(new File("en-pos-maxent.bin"));
```

I tried putting the en-pos-maxent.bin inside a new folder within the project("tagger/en-pos-maxent.bin"), inside the libs folder, or simply give the path where the en-pos-maxent.bin is put when downloaded("Users/ariel/Downloads/en-pos-maxent.bin"), it always give me the error: POS Tagger model file does not exist path: (the path I typed in)

Could anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `new File("filename")` the file is expected to be in the current working directory, I don't think that's different on Android. You can use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to get the current working directory. It's by default the directory you start the program from. You could also specify a full path like `new File("/full/path/filename")` instead.

Comment: I did put it in the current working directory, but it's like it just can't see it and ignore it even it's right there, is it possible that there is something wrong with the eclipse setting?

Answer (score 1):

In android the right way to add file to the application (inside APK) is to put into the `assets` folder. Then you can't get `File` object from assets folder but, you can create that File using a buffer or in you case just get it into the `InputStream`. For example if you will create `models` folder into the `assets` folder (`assets/models`), your code will look like this:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open("models/en-pos-maxent.bin");
POSModel posModel = new POSModel(inputStream);
```